# Unity: objects with rigid bodies and colliders going through each other?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision, rigid-bodies

Alright, so Im having an odd issue in Unity and cant find the answer there.I have 2 objects, one is movable by the player and the other is spawned. I need the player do be able to move (only along the z axis, meaning forwards/backwards/etc) this spawned object when he bumps into it, but only a little bit.

To accomplish this, Ive attached gravity rigid bodies to both and box colliders to both. Ive increased the mass and drag on the spawned object to make it hard to move here and frozen its rotation/some position to prevent flipping over:

[image]

And this does work, meaning the player does push the object and it seems to be a bit resistant, however Im having an odd bug.

I think due to the position/rotation being frozen, after pushing once my player will go THROUGH the object:

[image]

I cant have this. I have tried changing physics settings and set bounce threshold to 0[image]

But still having the problem. Decreasing time step basically froze my game. Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: How are you moving the player? Are you adding a force vector to the player, translating the player's transform, or setting the player's Rigidbody velocity? Because if you are using the Translate function, it places the player at a new vector position in each frame instead of smoothly "pushing" the player against physical objects in the scene. Use the AddForce or AddForceRelative (Rigidbody class) functions instead.

Comment: Ah, ok thats it but i need my player to move a set amount (1 tile) every time. How can I do that with add force